# transferring localstorage to another website

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I've been running RPG game on JS and changed website from fiamma.tk to another.
Now I somehow need to transfer user saves from fiamma.tk. Is it possible to do it with script?

Comment: Well, the problem is im not looking a way to share it with subdomain: i need to transfer from fiamma.tk to kino-govno.com.

Comment: Also, the problem that fiamma.tk is not being able to allow enough users to access it (this is free hosting) so iFrame is not an option :c